# Spring logback: logging uncaught exceptions

Tags: spring, logback

I would like to capture uncaught exceptions with log back, to cover cases like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dev")
public class DevController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DevController.class);

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/crash", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String crash() {

        int i = 1/0;

        return  "CRASH FINISHED " + i;
    }
}
```

My current logback configuration is:

```
<configuration debug="true"> 

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{50}:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/tmp/startgate.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{50}:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <smtpHost>localhost</smtpHost>
        <to>randomemail@randomdomain.com</to>
        <from>randomemail@randomdomain.com</from>
        <subject>LIVE ERROR: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%date %-5level %logger{35} - %message%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <if condition='property("ENVIRONMENT").contains("DEVELOPMENT")'>
        <then>
            <root level="INFO">
                <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
                <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
            </root>
        </then>
    </if>

    <if condition='property("ENVIRONMENT").contains("PRODUCTION")'>
        <then>
            <root level="ERROR">
                <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
            </root>
        </then>
    </if>

</configuration>
```

How can I be able to capture uncaught errors ?

**EDIT**
I am personally interested on sending such errors via email. Apparently the best way is using Global Exception Handlers. There is one tutorial here: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: The `DispatcherServlet` already catches such uncaught exceptions and logs them if it can't handle them.

Comment: How could I, for example, capture such exceptions and send it via email ?

Comment: For Spring MVC specifically, for exceptions coming from the handler methods, declare `@ExceptionHandler` methods.

Comment: You show me the right direction. Reading now http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc